# How to find longest words in all files using ForkJoin

Tags: java, file, fork-join

Using the resources of the Fork-Join framework, create an asynchronous multithreaded system to form a collection of words of maximum length from three text files.

How to find the longest words in all files?

In my case, I'm looking for each file separately, but I don't understand how to do it together, and I need to use **ForkJoin** framework.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File[] files = {
                new File("text"),
                new File("text2"),
                new File("text3")
        };

        MaxLengthWord sumOfDigits = new MaxLengthWord(files);

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

        final List<String> maxWords = pool.invoke(sumOfDigits);
        System.out.println(maxWords);

    }
}

class MaxLengthWord extends RecursiveTask<List<String>> {
    File[] files;

    public MaxLengthWord(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> compute() {
        if (files.length > 1) {
            return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(createSubtasks())
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(maxLengthWord -> maxLengthWord.join().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return processing(files);
        }
    }

    private Collection<MaxLengthWord> createSubtasks() {
        List<MaxLengthWord> subTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        subTasks.add(new MaxLengthWord(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(files, 0, files.length / 2)));
        subTasks.add(new MaxLengthWord(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(files, files.length / 2, files.length)));
        return subTasks;
    }

    private List<String> processing(File[] files) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String longest_word = "";
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(files[0])) {
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String word = sc.next();

                if (word.length() > longest_word.length()) {
                    longest_word = word;
                    result.clear();
                    result.add(longest_word);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result + " " + Thread.currentThread() + " " + files[0]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 files that have big difference in sizes this could be not ideal approach.
For example, if you have file A with 1 word, file B with 1 word and file C with 10,000,000 words , the sub tasks are unbalanced.

You can try different approach, and create sub task for each line in each file returning the max length word in each line.
Then aggregate the results to find the longest words overall.

Comment: combine in compute method, for example `int longest = maxLengthWords.stream()
                    .mapToInt(String::length)
                    .max()
                    .orElse(-1);

            return maxLengthWords.stream()
                    .filter(s -> s.length() == longest)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm of working with a `RecusiveAction` is the following:

- check if the task is small enough, to be executed by a `single thread` (in this case - there has to be `only one file` in the array);
- if the task has to be split create two subtasks;
- invoke `compute()` on the first subtask (no need to fork both subtasks);
- invoke `fork()` on the second subtask (task will be executed asynchronously on a different thread);
- invoke `join()` on the second subtask (`join()` is a blocking call and must be done after the invocation of `compute()` on the first subtask).

I've substituted `File` with a `Path` in my example because File API is legacy and discouraged to be used. Method `toFile()` allows to use `Path` when an instance of the `File` is required.

**RecursiveTask**

```
    public class MaxLengthWord extends RecursiveTask<List<String>> {
        private final Path[] files;

        public MaxLengthWord(Path[] files) {
            this.files = files;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> compute() {
            if (files.length == 0) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            if (files.length == 1) {
                return getLongestWords(files[0]);
            }
            else {
                MaxLengthWord task1 = new MaxLengthWord(Arrays.copyOf(files, files.length - 1));
                MaxLengthWord task2 = new MaxLengthWord(new Path[]{files[files.length - 1]});
                task2.fork();
                List<String> result = task1.compute();
                result.addAll(task2.join());
                return result;
            }
        }

        private List<String> getLongestWords(Path file) {
            List<String> words = getAllWordsFromFile(file);

            int maxLen = words.stream()
                    .mapToInt(String::length)
                    .max().orElse(0);

            return words.stream()
                    .filter(word -> word.length() == maxLen)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        private List<String> getAllWordsFromFile(Path file) {
            Pattern wordBoundary = Pattern.compile("\\b");

            try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
                return lines.flatMap(wordBoundary::splitAsStream)
                        .filter(word -> word.matches("\\p{L}+"))
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

**main** (don't forget to shutdown the pool)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path[] files = new Path[] {
                Path.of("a.txt"),
                Path.of("b.txt"),
                Path.of("c.txt")
        };
        ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        List<String> words = pool.invoke(new MaxLengthWord(files));
        System.out.println(words);
        pool.shutdown();
    }
```

**output** (all files are populated with quotes from Javadoc, these 4 words are happen to the longest)

```
[intermediate, Intermediate, intermediate, spliterator]
```

Comment: Can I combine in compute method, for example `int longest = maxLengthWords.stream()                     .mapToInt(String::length)                     .max()                     .orElse(-1);              return maxLengthWords.stream()                     .filter(s -> s.length() == longest)                     .collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: so you are looking for each file separately and not all

Comment: You `I need to use forkjoin` and I've shown in my example how to use fork-join framework correctly using `fork()`, `join()` and `compute()` to create and execute tasks recursively. In your approach you are not using the recursive nature of the task at all, every task will end-up on a separate thread. You used method `invokeAll()` from ExecutorService interface (note it doesn't belong to ForkJoin) that establishes asynchronous execution of all tasks and `blocks` the current thread, this doesn't allow reuse threads.

Comment: `so you are looking for each file separately and not all` ? only one thread can read file, that's obvious

Comment: but must be found in all files